# Can a finite group act transitively on an infinite set?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I had a question on my algebra exam, asking me to show that in case of a transitive action of a finite group $G$ on a set $X$, $|X|$ divides $|G|$. In case of a finite set, this is trivial, so I tried to see if I could come up with a possible counterexample with $X$ infinite (I failed to do so). Intuitively I feel like an infinite $X$ is "too big" for a finite group to act transitively on, but how would one show this formally?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given a fixed, arbitrary $x\in X$, transitivity means that the set
$$
Gx = \{gx\mid g\in G\}\subseteq X
$$
is equal to $X$. However, this set clearly cannot be larger than $G$.

Comment: Oh wow, that was dumb of me. I tried to proceed from the definition of transitivity and somehow missed this, silly of me!

Answer (score 2):

Let $y$ be a fixed element of $X$. For any element $x\in X$, transitivity implies there exists some $g\in G$ such that $g\cdot y=x$. This induces a injective map from $X\to G$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I understand now why a transitive action isn't possible in this case, but I don't understand what is meant by $g\cdot1=x$ in this context and how a map $X\to G$ can be specified.

Comment: Here, I think $1$ is meant to be some element of $X$ fixed at the start.

Comment: So a group action defines a left multiplication map (at least the way I see it) on a set. So, given the group action $\phi: G\times X\to X$, for every $x\in X$, there exists $g\in G$ such that $(g,y)\mapsto x$ by transitivity.

Comment: @DonThousand What is $1$? $X$ is just an arbitrary set -- it does not come equipped with an identity element, or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, if $X$ is empty, any group acts transitively on $X$, but $\lvert X \rvert = 0$ cannot divide $\lvert G \rvert$, so the claim might actually be false (depending on whether or not you allow $G$-sets to be empty).

Anyway, suppose $G$ is a finite group acting transitively on a *nonempty* set $X$. Since $X$ is nonempty, we may pick some $x \in X$. Then define $a : G \to X$ by $a(g) = g \cdot x$. By definition of transitive action, $a$ is surjective. Thus, $\lvert G \rvert \geq \lvert X \rvert$, so $X$ is finite.

Comment: I cannot recall if it was specified that $X$ was non-empty or not. The question itself was dumb, shouldn't have posted it, thanks for an answer anyway!

Comment: Everyone misses easy arguments when they're new to a topic :)

Comment: A $G$-set can be empty, in which case it somewhat depends whether one would call the action transitive; personally I think the criterion should be "having a single orbit", and the empty set fails this, so I should say "non transitive" here. That would save the $|X|$ divides $|G|$ claim (which does not hold if $X=\emptyset$, but in that case "transitive action" hypothesisis not satisfied). But definitely **the empty set is finite** so the point is moot; the conclusion of your second paragraph holds without the "nonempty $X$" hypothesis, regardless of your opinion about "transitive".

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I agree with everything you said :) Probably "has exactly one orbit" is a better definition of "transitive". Anyway, I just wanted to emphasize that all the proofs presented here rely crucially on an assumption that $X$ is nonempty -- I wanted to make this assumption explicit in my answer. Of course the conclusion that $X$ is finite holds when $X$ is empty as well!

Comment: Thanks, and my apologies for suggesting that it is a problem when the conclusion of a statement is valid in some cases where some hypothesis is not satisfied; this is of course totally normal. (What is a bit special in this case that there is only one way in which the "nonempty" hypothesis can fail, and the conclusion happens to not be affected by it; yet the argument does use the hypothesis.)

Answer (score 1):

For a sort of a sledgehammer here, it falls out of the *orbit-stabilizer theorem*.  For the "size" of the orbit of any element is the index of the stabilizer: $[G:G_x]=|Gx|$.  But $[G:G_x]\le|G|$.  That'll crack this nut.

Comment: +1, but I would say what really counts here is that the quotient of a finite set by any equivalence relation is finite. Here the orbit of any $x$, which is all of $X$ for a transitive action, is in bijection with $G/G_x$, and without any further ado that makes $X$ finite.

Answer (score 0):

If $G$ acts transitively on $X$, then, given $x\in X$, for every $y\in X$ there is some $g\in G$ such that $y=g\cdot x$. This is precisely the condition for a *surjection* $f_x\colon G\longrightarrow X$ to exist. Therefore the cardinality of $G$ is *at least* equal to the one of $X$.

(Incidentally, since by group action's axioms distinct $x$'s induce distinct $f_x$'s, there are $|X|$ of such surjections.)